# Match empty line in an alias .bashrc

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I would like to bind my empty line in my bash to a specific command (for example pwd, ls, ...), like so :

```
$<enter>
$/home/
```

I tried

```
// ~/.bashrc
alias ="pwd"
```

But obviously this was rejected :

```
-bash: alias: =pwd: not found
```

Any idea ?

Comment: you omit the variable name after alias the command mus be like `alias var_name="pwd"`

Comment: the purpose of this question is matching an empty line in the bash, so no variable name must be provided i think ...

Comment: Its impossible !

Comment: It's not possible, because an empty line isn't a concrete thing that `bash` recognizes; it's simply more whitespace between two commands that is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='_L="$(history 1)"; [ "$_L" != "$_X" ] || echo $PWD && _X="$_L"'
```

Comment: Great ! Can you explain how it works ?

Comment: The bash environment variable PROMPT_COMMAND contains a regular bash command that is executed just before the command prompt is displayed.  so this isn't a proper answer for this question ! because question is abut alias without `name`

Comment: yeah but as it might not be possible it's a great solution too